# Jenkins job run on apperance of file with current date in name

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

I wanted to ask if there is a way of configuring the Jenkins job to run when file with name pattern "**ABCD.EFGH.YYYYMMDD.OK**" (where YYYYMMDD is the current date) will appear in the specific directory?

Is there any plugin that could help?

Kind regards,
Chris

Comment: How should Jenkins know that?

Comment: for example by using FS plugin to monitor if the directory content was change or if the file with specified name was put into directory. The problem is the file name, that has the current date in name.